# Datepicker and clone function from JQuery issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, clone

this is the part from the js, which does the cloning stuff.

```
$(document).on("click", ".adauga_incasare", function () {
    $('.incasari:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.incasari:last');
    $(".incasari:last").find(".data_incasare_container label b").remove(); //remove label
    $(".incasari:last").find(".suma_incasare_container label b").remove();
    $(".coscos").css("padding-top", "4px");
    $(".incasari:first").find(".coscos").css("padding-top", "20px");)
};
```

this is the html code :

```
<div class="incasari first hasData">
    <div class="data_incasare_container">
        <label><b>Data</b>
        </label>
        <input class="data_incasare datepicker_incasare" name="data_incasare" type="text">
        <label class="data_incasare_hidden">
            <?php echo $value->date; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="suma_incasare_container">
        <label><b>Suma</b>
        </label>
        <input class="suma_incasare" type="text" maxlength="8" name="suma_incasare">
        <label class="suma_incasare_hidden">
            <?php echo $value->received; ?></label>
    </div>
    <div class="coscos"> <a class="stergereIncasare" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-trash sterge_incasare" id = "<?php  echo $value->id; ?>"></i></a>

        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="incasare_action">
            <input class="btn btn-success salveaza_incasare" type="button" style="margin-left:50px;width:80px;height:30px;float:left;" value="Salveaza"></input> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="del_incasare delrow"></a>

        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div> <a href="#" class="adauga_incasare">+ Adauga incasare noua</a>
```

and the code from the datepicker :

```
$('.datepicker_incasare').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: "-2Y",
    maxDate: "+2Y"
});
```

The problem appears when I press a button, which does the cloning stuff, and after that the datepicker does not work on the input.

In the image below you can see the result: 
[image]

When I save a new row and it refreshes the page, it works. But it does not work after cloning.

What should I do ? thx

for this script :

```
$foo =  $('.incasari:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.incasari:last');
                            $(".incasari:last").find(".data_incasare_container label b").remove(); //remove label
                            $(".incasari:last").find(".suma_incasare_container label b").remove();
                            $(".coscos").css("padding-top", "4px");
                            $(".incasari:first").find(".coscos").css("padding-top", "20px");
                            $foo.datepicker({
                               changeMonth: true,
                               changeYear: true,
                               dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                               minDate: "-2Y",
                               maxDate: "+2Y"
                          });
```

this is the result: [image]

Comment: you need to bind the datepicker to the new cloned element. Put your datepicker initialization inside a function and call that function after your clone.

Comment: can you please post an answer :) to make you more understandable , from my point of view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize the cloned datepicker by simpy put the call into your click handler

```
$(document).on("click", ".adauga_incasare", function () {
   $foo =  $('.incasari:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.incasari:last');
    $(".incasari:last").find(".data_incasare_container label b").remove(); //remove label
    $(".incasari:last").find(".suma_incasare_container label b").remove();
    $(".coscos").css("padding-top", "4px");
    $(".incasari:first").find(".coscos").css("padding-top", "20px");)
    $foo.datepicker({
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true,
       dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
       minDate: "-2Y",
       maxDate: "+2Y"
  });
};
```

Comment: it works, but now it is not working for the element which is not cloned :|

Comment: check my edit, i assigned the cloned node to a variable and call datepicker only for the cloned node, is it working like that =?

Comment: it totally messed up the design of the datepicker, please check my post and see the result :)

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment you need to bind after insertion.

```
$(document).on("click", ".adauga_incasare", function () {
    $foo =  $('.incasari:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.incasari:last');
    $(".incasari:last").find(".data_incasare_container label b").remove(); //remove label
    $(".incasari:last").find(".suma_incasare_container label b").remove();
    $(".coscos").css("padding-top", "4px");
    $(".incasari:first").find(".coscos").css("padding-top", "20px");)
    $foo.datepicker({  //really this should be just the init executed in a callback
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      minDate: "-2Y",
      maxDate: "+2Y"
    });
};

function initDatePicker(){
    $('.datepicker_incasari').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    minDate: "-2Y",
    maxDate: "+2Y"
    });
}
```

then in your document load call initDatePicker for first initialization

```
$(function() {
  initDatePicker();
});
```

Comment: I tried this version and it works for only normal inputs, not the cloning ones

Comment: it's because the initDatePicker was being called before everything was done updating in the dom. I've combined mine and the other answer.